# Security certificate has been revoked Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, security, anti-virus, malware

Some days back I started receiving below message in Chrome whenever I open site with a secure connection such as https://www.facebook.com or https://www.gmail.com

*Security certificate has been revoked*

I was able to access the same two sites in other browsers.

See error snapshot at: https://chrome-a-googleproductforums-com.googlegroups.com/attach/f60e44de58e4f45e/Twitter%20Not%20Trusted.JPG?view=1&part=2

Upon Googling about the error I found that my system has been infected with malware. I did System Restore (using SysRestore Pro) but failed and system was unable to restore to previous state. Then I tried to run the antivirus scan from Micrsoft Security Essentials but the application was unable to open. Also whenever I downloaded/open any antivirus/anti-malware or such similar kind of tools, it denied each time, throwing different errors for each application. Moreover the antivirus application downloaded was considered as a virus!!! (too funny) and downloaded remain incomplete

I then tried to use Windows 7 System Restore but that too failed and after some steps of system recovery it threw below error

*Windows failed to start. A recent hardware of software change might be the cause. To fix the problem 

1.Insert your Windows installation disc and restart the computer. 

2.Choose your language settings, and then click "Next". 

3.Click "Repair your computer." 

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.


File: \Boot\BCD 


Status: 0x000000f*

My concern here is how to remove malware from the system once I start my PC??

Comment: Check your system/hardware clock, is it correct? The certificates are time-based so that can be an issue. Though, one browser only.. Also, are your root certificate authorities in place in Chrome's settings?

Comment: What software was detecting your downloads as malware?  Did you follow the instructions in the error?

Comment: @Alex - If I am not mistaken Chrome uses the operating systems Certificate Store.  Firefox uses its own Store.  This means that Chrome and IE should both present the same problem and it possible firefox would not.  Its not mentioned what the other browsers are.  Opera and Safari should both use the operating system's certificate store also.

Comment: @Alex: Yes I checked that my system clock was running correct. Moreover I have not touched/changed certificate settings in Chrome

Comment: @Ramhound: IE was detecting my downloads as corrupt. The instructions were something like "Virus detected file deleted" although the file was an genuine Microsoft Security Essentials setup

Comment: Seems like you seriously have one of these bad boys that pretend to be real anti-viruses which are ANTI-anti-viruses :) They can even offer you to buy a full version for like $100 and change nothing, lol. They like to throw things like this at you, blocking internet access, flagging your executables as viruses, etc. Get a good anti-virus (the one you trust) and scan the hell out of it

Comment: @Alex: Yeah the malware/virus is so terrible that even the System Restore (Windows Default + Third Party) failed as well as the boot file of my machine has gone bad (See question for the error 0x000000f)

Comment: I guess system restore utility isn't gonna help here. If you're able to run an anti-virus, go ahead and scan you PC

Comment: @Alex: I won't be able to run antivirus until I get my system up & running.Since the boot file has gone bad/corrupt, I have to restore the file first and then I could run an antivirus

Comment: @Alex: In continunation to previous comment, When I run the antivirus/anti-malware application, it gave me an error of not being accessible. The antivirus applicaton wasn't being open and was also hidden from system tray.

Comment: Check [this one out](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) on how to restore the bootloader

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the link. I am planning to create a system restore disk for Windows 7. But if my pc has Windows 7 Pro SP1 does it matter if I use Windows 7 Pro DVD??

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - You should use a Windows 7 Pro already loaded with Service Pack 1.  You need to solve the booting problem before we can help you.  There are tools to boot into a disk to scan your hdd.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option 1
```

Repair windows start-up by booting from windows DVD

If you can get it to boot, use [chameleon](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/chameleon/) to get malwarebytes running.

Run malware bytes full scan and find out the full damage report. Clean up if possible and then check for rootkits using [anti-rootkit](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/mbar/).

I would then run a full scan with your favourite flavour of AV until you're happy your system is clean.

```
Option 2
```

Just get your data off using a linux live DVD and re-install windows. Run the anti-rootkit as soon as windows is installed.

I like option 2

Answer (score 0):

Run `msconfig` and select the Boot tab. Select Safe and networking and then apply. Restart the computer and it will boot in safe mode with internet access but the virus wont be active.

Download microsoft safe scanner from the microsot website and run it. The safe scanner will find the maleware/virus and remove it and ask if you want to reboot. Before you reboot run msconfig again and select the boot tab. De-select the safe option and apply.

Restart the computer and it should be good.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. How do you know that the virus won't be active when booting into safe mode?